# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 55.28.36.18:587 at TCPConnectWrap

Tags: node.js, gmail, sendmail

I'm sending email using nodemailer.
I just follow the sample [here](https://codeburst.io/sending-an-email-using-nodemailer-gmail-7cfa0712a799).
But I got error like below.

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 55.28.36.18:587
>
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
>
> errno: -4039,
>
> code: 'ESOCKET',
>
> syscall: 'connect',
>
> address: '55.28.36.18',
>
> port: 587,
>
> command: 'CONN' }

I tried to change port number and other things but can't fix this.

Please tell me what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your proxy settings first.
Some of these errors are due to proxy setting.
The sample you followed is working fine on my side.